# android keep memory hungry bakground service

Tags: android, memory, service, android-service

In my app I need to download, process and store (in SQLite) around 400MiB of HTML documents. Problem is that inserting that much data into sqlite (~60k inserts) takes very long time. I use transaction and precompiled statements, but it still takes a lot of time. On low-end phones it can take upto two hours. On high end ones it is atleast 10-12 minutes.

All this is done in an `IntentService`, so it can continue while the app is in the background. To speed-up things the most I ask for a `largeHeap` in the manifest and set the transaction size based on the memory available for a VM. Thanks to this the service can easily take 100MiB of RAM. Because of this the service is killed/paused very shortly after the app goes into the background. I use `startForeground` in the `Service` and display the download progress, but it does not help.

This happens even on high-end phones like HTC One X and even if the system has more then 200MiB of free RAM during this process.

Is there a way to protect this memory hungry service from being killed by the system? Currently the process looks like it restarts and one segment is being processed in a loop, because the system kills before it finishes that segment. Setting a smaller transaction size will reduce the memory consumption but will multiply the time, where more then 25 minutes is not acceptable on high end phones.

**EDIT:**
This is issue mainly on Android 4 and newer. Android 2.3.3 looks much more stable.

Comment: You need to review the design of your program. Consider storing the documents on the SD card and with indexes in the database. It's a data replication/synchronisation problem and can be done piecemeal as a background service. But you cannot escape the fact that it will take a long time. Hence think hard about the design.

Comment: @GR8DAN Months ago I experimented with the storage options and storing those documents as files was discarded because it is around 60 thousands (yes sixty) documents i.e. files. At the moment it is an SQLite database on the SD card and all of those documents are unique. In comparison, the same process takes around 7 minutes on an iPhone 5, but the app cannot go into background.

Answer (score 0):

> In my app I need to download, process and store (in SQLite) around 400MiB of HTML documents.

Consider downloading and storing a 400MiB SQLite database with the documents, where the database is prepared on a server.

Also, please only download and store that database on external storage, at least for Android 2.x devices.

> Is there a way to protect this memory hungry service from being killed by the system?

No.

> Months ago I experimented with the storage options and storing those documents as files was discarded because it is around 60 thousands (yes sixty) documents i.e. files.

That does not explain why you think a 400MiB database is superior to a directory structure containing 60,000 files.

Comment: I know that the best would be to prepare the DB on the server. I told it several times to my client, but the server guys will not do that in any near (even distant) future. Database is on the SD card (in app's external cache direrctory). In my tests opening a directory with 60k files was very slow. Dividing it into folders get me to ~10k directories with 6 files in average, still slow especially on slow SD cards.

Comment: @shelll: "but the server guys will not do that in any near (even distant) future" -- then the client should not complain about the processing speed.

Comment: :D I know. Another problem is, that the service dies in the background. I just figured out that the service is not killed that often, but I get a server connection timeouts even though I acquire `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` to prevent CPU shutdown and a `WifiLock` with `WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF`.

Comment: @shelll: All those will do is ensure that the hardware won't get in your way. Depending on your server protocol and setup, if you aren't doing some sort of "heartbeat" back to the server, it's possible the server will think you're gone after an extended period and terminate the socket from its side or otherwise give up.

Comment: I get this timeout only when I quickly turn off the display during the very first connection, then it gets timed out. Other connections while the display is of have no problem. That is weird.